# Passing function pointer with string parameter from Swift to Obj C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, pointers, objective-c++

I'm currently at an impasse in calling a function in my C++ dynamic library that requires a function pointer to be passed, where that function pointer has a parameter of a pointer to a string, from a Swift test harness I've built. I have a feeling that either my function declaration in my Obj C++ header in my test harness is incorrect, or I'm improperly formatting the call in Swift.

The header in my Obj C++ library (implementation is in my .mm file):

```
@interface Objective_CPP : NSObject
- (void)InitCppDriver:(customCallbackType)readCompleteCallback;
@end
```

The corresponding file my bridging header links to in my test harness (unsure if this is equivalent to the declaration in my library project) :

```
@interface Objective_CPP : NSObject
- (void) InitCppDriver:(void (*)(const wchar_t* data))readCompleteCallback;
@end
```

The declaration of my customCallbackType in my library project (C++):

```
typedef void(*customCallbackType)(const wchar_t* json);

extern customCallbackType frReadCompleteCallback;
```

My implementation of my InitCppDriver in my library:

```
@implementation Objective_CPP
- (void)InitCppDriver:(customCallbackType)readMeterComplCallback
   {
   ...
   }
@end
```

When I go to call my InitCppDriver function in my test harness (Swift):

```
var ptrStr: UnsafePointer<wchar_t>?;
Objective_CPP().InitCppDriver(callBack(outString: ptrStr));
...
func callBack (outString:UnsafePointer<wchar_t>?){
   //code manipulating string here
}
```

I've tried passing a closure and a number of other function definitions, but the error I end up getting is a variant of this for everything I have tried:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type
>   '(@convention(c) (UnsafePointer?) -> Void)!'

I've been able to call my InitCppDriver function successfully without the parameter of having a function pointer passed into it, but I cannot seem to figure out the syntax/setup of how to call that same function with a function pointer parameter. Any insight on how to do this would be great - I don't work in Obj-C or Swift often and have been stuck on this for a little too long now.

If there is any other context I can give to the issue I'll be happy to post up more code.

Thanks!!

Comment: A Swift function is no C function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking your callback and trying to pass the return value (which is `()`) to the C++ function. You should just say `Objective_CPP().InitCppDriver(callBack(outString:))` instead.

Comment: This was a majority of the problem. I ended up realizing I had to declare callBack outside of the class (not as a method function), and then passing that function without parameters on it (so it would not be invoked). This allowed the callback to be called from the C++ library. After that I had to edit my function to send the length of the wchar_t back, and converted that into a swift Data object which allowed me to make an NSString and successfully get my string in my Swift harness.